# Extend Nav bar on Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, web

I am building a website and I was wondering if I can extend the navbar to full width but keep the content below in the same container. Just learning the ropes. Site is www.blacksheephostel.ie

Answer (score 0):

add display:flex to your main container and then set the min-width of your nav bar to the width of the container and flex-wrap:wrap so this will have your nav-bar take up the top space of the container and the content will wrap below it in the same container.

If possible learn flexbox , its a great CSS tool

Hope this helps,
Take care and happy coding

Comment: Thanks Im not exactly sure where I need to do that. Im using wordpress. Thanks

Comment: This will go in the style.css inside the container element that holds both your navbar and content..if you have a link that i can reference then i might be able to provide a more precise answer